# How do I assign a role to a user in gcp for only 24 hours using gcloud cli?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, gcloud-cli, gcp-iam, common-expression-language

I am trying to assign a role to a user only for 24 hours.I was using gcloud command for this and condition statement within the command.

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding project_name --member='user:my_email_address@gmail.com' --role='roles/storage.admin' --condition='expression=request.time < request.time + duration('86400s') , title = sample_condition, description = sample_description'
```

This was throwing an error stating that
ERROR: (gcloud.projects.add-iam-policy-binding) argument --condition: valid keys are [None, Description,expression,title]; recieved: title

I believe the command without --condition is working fine
Iam new to common expression language and any help is greatly appreciated !

Comment: As guillaume Suggested is correct Refer to this official [doc](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/projects/add-iam-policy-binding) about gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding

Comment: **You have other options to obtain the required temporary access.**


[Cloud Identity Premium](https://cloud.google.com/identity/docs/how-to/manage-expirations) allows for short-term user allocations.You can add the user to a temporary group that has the necessary role, set the group expiration date to 24 hours, and create the group.

Comment: Create a [service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-account-creds) with the necessary rights, then issue temporary access tokens for the account which have a 24-hour expiration date. You may then use the tokens to access GCP 
resources via the service account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no condition to grant access for a duration. You must compute the end time and set it as condition, something like thisfollowing

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding <PROJECT_ID> \
    --member=<your member> \
    --role=<your rols> \
  --condition=expression="request.time < timestamp('$(date -d "now + 24 hours" +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")')",title="Expires on $(date -d "now + 24 hours" +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")"
```

Comment: Thanks ! I was using this command in a groovy script and in the groovy script I created a timestamp for the next date and passed it as a variable in the gcloud command